# Jquery ajax html replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

My question is simple
I receive string and a number but only number show up
How I can display both?

```
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "data.php",
            data: "act="+nr,
            success: function (result) {

                var arr = JSON.parse(result);

                if ($.isArray(arr) == true) {
                    $.each(arr, function (i, n) {
                        $('#s_main #s_info').html("<p>+" + n + "</p>")
                    });

                }

            }
        })
    }); //ends here
```

---

my php:

```
$act = $_POST['act'];

$output =array();
$act2 = "TXT!!!";
array_push($output,$act);

echo json_encode($output);
```

**By the way when i use append instead of html the result is correct but it will stack on and not delete the previous data**

Comment: You have not shown exactly *how* you "receive" the strings and numbers. What exactly does the result JSON look like?  Without knowing that, it's pretty hard to help.

Comment: If you console.log(n) you get the expected result?

Comment: Do you could post your JSON result structure? - [estevao_lucas](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1394414/estevao-lucas) via

Answer (score 0):

What you are getting in return is a JSON *Object*.

```
if ($.isArray(arr) == true)
```

This line shouldn't return true becuase an object is not an array.  If  the `JSON.parse()` did not work it will return a value that will equate to false.  So you can simply test the returned object to see if it was successful.

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(result);

if (jsonObj) {
  $.each(jsonObj, function (index, value) {
    $('#s_main #s_info').html("<p>+" + value + "</p>")
  });
}
```